# Laravel encrypt password before storing on DB and decrypt it to use on email settings

Tags: laravel, encryption, mailer, crypt

I followed this tutorial to create dynamic email settings stored on db.

https://kayike.medium.com/enable-unique-and-dynamic-smtp-mail-settings-for-each-user-laravel-48e320d381ec

The only problem is that the password is not encrypted. I would like to encrypt it before storing on db and decrypt it before using on MailServiceProvider.

I tried to use bcrypt but it can't be de-crypted. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the docs for encryption: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption

`encrypting` password:

```
$encrypted = crypt::encryptString($password);
```

//store this to database

`decrypting` password:

```
$decrypted_password = crypt::decryptString($encrypted);
//use this for mailer settings
```

Note: don't forget to use namespace `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;`
in the controller

Additional Note for bcrypt:
encryption-decryption is different than hashing, bcrypt is a hashing formula which can't be decrypted (one way process).

Comment: Great solution!! Thanks a lot!